# Generating sequential numbers using BitSet

Tags: java, bitset

I would like to store numbers, from 1 to N,  sequentially in an array of BitSet. Is there an alternate solution apart from using the set() method on each number? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are operations for setting a range of bits in a `BitSet`; e.g. [`set(from, to, value)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#set%28int,%20int,%20boolean%29).  So for example,

```
    for (int i = from; i < to; i++) {
        bitset.set(i, true);
    }
```

is equivalent to

```
    bitset.set(from, to, true);
```

The latter form is most likely a lot faster.